# Tracking Traffic Through a Certain Page

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking for some help with the Google Analytics Behavior Flow.

I want to track all the traffic through a section of our site that ends up going to another particular section of my web site.

Any advice on how to get this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use segments to view this report for only the users that have viewed both sections of your site.

1. Click "+ Add Segment" from the behavior flow report.
2. Click the red "+ New Segment" button.
3. Click "Advanced conditions".
4. Where it says "Ad Content", change it to "Page".
5. Enter an expression that matches the URLs for the first section of your site.
6. Hit the "AND" button to add another condition.
7. Also use "Page" with an expression to match the URLs for the second section of your site.
8. Name your segment where it says "Segment Name" [image: segment for two pages]
9. Use the blue "Save" button to apply the segment
10. Remove the "All sessions" segment if it is still applied as well

Now your report should just have the traffic that you want to examine in more detail.

Comment: This is helpful.  I changed the first page to be "Landing Page" and then that was exactly what I wanted.